# How do you use a bundled Angular 2 application in the browser?

Tags: typescript, angular

I've tried to compile all TypeScript code into one single Javascript file. But whenever I try to import that file using SystemJS, the webpage is stuck at `loading...`

I use gulp to compile the typescript files into one single Javascript file and then copy to the `dist` folder.

Gulp Task:

```
gulp.task("dist:compileTSConcat", function() {
  return gulp.src("./app/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(ts({
      typescript: require('typescript'), // In my package.json I have "typescript": "1.8.2"
      target: 'ES5',
      module: 'system',
      moduleResolution: 'node',
      experimentalDecorators: true,
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
      outFile: 'app.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
})
```

SystemJS Import code in webpage:

```
...
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.4/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.23/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.23/system-register-only.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      //System.config({});
      System.import('app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your JS file in a `script` tag and import the entry point module of your application:

```
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

If you bootstrap your Angular 2 application in a file called `boot.ts` located under the `app` folder.

Comment: After doing this, I get an error - `EXCEPTION: The selector "just-some-studying" did not match any elements`

Comment: This is when your main component has a selector that can't be found in the main HTML page. You should have `<just-some-studying>Loading...</just-some-studying>` in this HTML page.

Comment: Could you tell us how to define your main component in the HTML file?

Comment: I use `<body>
    <just-some-studying>Loading...</just-some-studying>
  </body>` to define the selector for the app.

Comment: @Sasxa I tried moving the selector tag, but this didn't change anything. I still get the error.

Comment: This error has also popped up numerous times before during development. The most obvious solution was to refresh, but this doesn't work now.

Comment: Check if your templates/styles are being loaded correctly (Devtools>Network), this can sometimes messup the parser.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed after changing "app/boot" to "app" in System.import. I also made sure all script tags were below my selector tag. Thanks.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I'll mark your answer as correct after you change "app/boot" to "app". Thanks for your help, Thierry and Sasxa.